# Arduino Publisher/Suscriber for Gazebo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a program in arduino that is reading the values from a flex sensor, and publish them in a topic like the Example in
[here/Rosserial_arduino/publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello%20World).

Now I need to send that values to gazebo, to move a 3D object. I tried to make a suscriber like all the examples in rosserial_arduino tutorials, and like the examples of ROS tutorials but the question is that in all the examples the suscriber and the Publisher are .cpp files and in this case the publisher is the arduino that is a .ino file.
Anyway tried to make a file .cpp for the suscriber, and add the line

> rosbuild_add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)

in the Cmakelists.txt but of course here is an error cause he didn't find the topic that he is trying to suscribe.

Really I don't know how to communicate the arduino with gazebo. or create a suscriber that i can use in gazebo that listen the publication of arduino.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48180/arduino-publisher/suscriber-for-gazebo/) by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2012-11-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-11-13**:
Move a 3D object how? What is the type of the message are you currently publishing?

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on 2012-11-13**:
Actually i have a kind of hand, made by boxes, each one of the parts of the fingers is a diferent box, is defined in a .urdf file with joints,etc. The type of message i'm publishin' is a float. is a value that gives me the sensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Better answer found [to this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/48290/how-to-move-a-gazebo-object-with-rosserial_arduino-values-from-flex-sensor/)

I have not done this myself.. It's on the list though...
I think that the closest tutorial out there to a what you'd like to do (right now) is the [control_model](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.2/intermediate/control_model) tutorial. (The [animate_joint tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.2/control_robot/animate_joint) does something a little different.) You also should take a look at how the [simple_arm.model](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/002cf4c39517/sdf/models/simple_arm.model) is set up. You'd to add the logic to subscribe to the topic(s) that have the control information.

The essence of what you're asking has been done (in urdf not sdf) in the [sr_hand](http://www.ros.org/wiki/sr_hand) package, so I would also take a look at their tutorials, and their [source code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eshadowrobot/sr-ros-interface/trunk/view/head:/sr_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_controller_manager.cpp).

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0